# Merging PHP array to multidimensional array from another array

Tags: php, arrays

i have 3 array

```
Array(
[0] => 0.123
[1] => 0.221)

Array(
[0] => abcd
[1] => defg)

Array(
[0] => 10000
[1] => 20000)
```

Is it possible to add key and merge them to a multidimensional array in this format ?

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
     [si] => 0.123
     [ri] => abcd
     [pr] => 10000)
[1] = > Array(
     [si] => 0,221
     [ri] => defg
     [pr] => 20000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short solution with `array_map` and `array_combine` functions:

```
$arr1 = [ 0.123, 0.221 ];
$arr2 = [ 'abcd', 'defg' ];
$arr3 = [ 10000, 20000 ];

$result = array_map(function($v){
    return array_combine(['si', 'ri', 'pr'], $v);
}, array_map(null, $arr1, $arr2, $arr3));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [si] => 0.123
            [ri] => abcd
            [pr] => 10000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [si] => 0.221
            [ri] => defg
            [pr] => 20000
        )
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php